# Fill holes in compound path with color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, path

I need assistant to figure out how can I fill the empty holes within compound path with color using *Adobe Illustrator*.

[image: .SVG compound path]

[Download .SVG file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uc5x8q0rhq73eoi/comment.svg?dl=0)

Comment: @Benteh fill the circular holes with color. I tried nothing so far due to lack experience with Illustrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way to do what you require.

- Firstly, select the shape using the Selection tool (V).
- Next, from the Object menu, select Compound Path > Release.

The items should all become separate shapes which can be selected individually.

Comment: Using release didn`t fully worked since selection tool apply only to the whole path. Applying "isolate selected group" did help. Thanks for your guidance.